# Set the absolute path for an Image in a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, url, firefox

I would like to set the absolute path of an Image in a Canvas. I have some Divs which have background images. Now I would like to draw this image on a canvas.

My try:

```
base_image = new Image();
var bg = $('#imagebox').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
alert(bg); // The background image is right
base_image.src = bg;
```

The background image url is right. It is a String like www.domain.de/image.jpg.
When I tried it with Google Chrome, it worked well. But Firefox adds the old url to the new url: http://domain.de/http://domain.de/image.jpg.

Do you have any idea what causes this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`www.domain.de/image.jpg` is not a valid URL. `http://www.domain.de/image.jpg` would be.
Chrome seems to be more forgiving in this regard.

Since it is not a valid URL, Firefox assumes it it a relative path and constructs a valid URL with it and the current base URL, e.g. `http://www.domain.de/` (base URL) + `www.domain.de/image.jpg` -> `http://www.domain.de/www.domain.de/image.jpg`.